# Word for someone who is annoying and pathetic, who also spends most time orbiting people

Tags: single-word-requests

The word is important for me trying to figure out which of the people I know fit that category, it's just that simple.

What's the closest thing to it?

Answer (score 2):

Such a person might be described as **clingy**.

Via [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clingy):

> tending to stay very close to someone (such as a parent) for emotional support, protection, etc.

I've personally always heard the word used with a negative connotation. [Example usage](https://www.bustle.com/life/153261-11-signs-your-partner-is-too-clingy-what-to-do-about-it):

> Chances are you don't have much of interest in being the clingy one in a relationship. It comes with a whole slew of negative connotations — worst of all being jealousy.